# How to add a table in wp_editor?

Tags: php, plugins, wordpress, wp-editor

I am looking out to add a table tool in the wordpress editor. But cannot find any way to do this.

Can anyone plz tell me the best possible way to add any table tool in the editor without plugin?

Comment: if you are looking for a best way but without any plugin, get ready to write some php, html, css and javascript to do it yourself.

Comment: But how ?? can i help you ??